# Is there a way to register that one property depends on another?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

What I mean by this is: suppose there are `IsCompliant` and `ShowWarning` properties on the ViewModel.  The UI has some message bound to ShowWarning, and if the ViewModel is not compliant, along with some other conditions, we want to show the warning.  So, I'm coding it like this:

```
    private bool mbIsCompliant;
    public bool IsCompliant
    {
        get { return mbIsCompliant; }
        set
        { 
            mbIsCompliant = value; 

            RaisePropertyChanged (() => IsCompliant); 
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => ShowWarning); 
        }
    }

    public bool ShowWarning
    {
        get { return !IsCompliant && [other conditions]; }
    }
```

Note that double `RaisePropertyChanged` call in the setter for `IsCompliant`, to trigger the update for the view bound to `ShowWarning`.  But this feels klunky to me, because each property has a sprinkling of these calls throughout the ViewModel.

What I would prefer is a way to have a table of dependencies that I can register in the constructor, and have MVVMCross keep track of the fact that if Property A changed, then Property B also changed, and so on.  In this way, each property keeps track of itself, and the class as a whole manages the dependency relationship between the properties.

Does this exist?  Is it a reasonable idea, or is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no 'one way' to do this, but a few people have experimented with different techniques including general INotifyPropertyChanged interception, some attribute based extensions and some Aspect Oriented Programming techniques

For some examples and information on these, see:

- http://twincoders.com/blog/codigo-limpio-con-fody/ (via http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/awesome-clean-viewmodels-via-fody.html)
- https://github.com/zleao/MvvmCross-PropertyChangedEventPropagation
- http://slodge.blogspot.ca/2013/07/intercepting-raisepropertychanged.html
- http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/intercepting-raisepropertychanged.html

Comment: Wow, that's a lot to assimilate.  I'll work my way through these links and see what seems best for me.  Thanks!